# Que função utilizo para retornar ou mostrar os todos os números iguais de uma lista de 20 numeros?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
n = []
for i in range(20):
    n.append(int(input("Digite o número: ")))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assim:

```
import collections
print([item for item, contagem in collections.Counter(n).items() if contagem > 1])
```

Ou assim:

```
print(set([item for item in n if n.count(item) > 1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections

n = []
for i in range(20):
    n.append(random.randrange(6))

print(n) # esta é a lista


m = collections.defaultdict(int)

for i in n:
    m[i] += 1

print(dict(m)) # apresenta o item e a quantidade

print(sorted(m.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)) # apresenta o item ordenado pela quantidade
```